# SQL injection - PHP - prevent with data types specification

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

Is this enough to be safe from SQL injections:

```
$value1 = htmlspecialchars($_GET['input1'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$value2 = intval($_GET['input2']);
SELECT xy FROM a WHERE a = '$value1' AND b = $value2;
```

Eg.: Every string input is in '...' and every non-string input is converted to number via intval / doubleval.

Query is run over mysqli_

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` is **not** for SQL injection prevention; it's purely for outputting certain characters to HTML - that's it. So, no.

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: More effort for less safety doesn't usually make sense. And once you read up on parameter binding with mysqli, you'll see why everyone uses PDO instead.

Comment: Was going to post, but the bottom line is that `htmlspecialchars` does nothing to sterilize rogue incoming strings.  A malicious user could fairly easily inject your script to do bad things.  Such sterilization functions _do_ exist (MySQL has them, for instance), but you'd best leave this up to the database to handle.

Comment: It's amazing how developers come up with so many complicated and ineffective solutions to SQL injection, apparently to avoid using the method that is both secure and simple: query parameters.